# How to get a selected list of GitHub issues in octocat with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, github-api, octokit

Basically I am using [octokit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb) trying to add a particular set of GitHub issues, based on their *issue number*, to an issue list.

The summary of the code is similar to this:

```rb
require 'octokit'

client = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: ENV['GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN'], accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3+json')

REPO = 'USERNAME/SOME-GH-REPO'.freeze

#client.issue(REPO, 1)                     # Returns {}
#client.issues(REPO, :state => 'all')      # Returns [{}]

def pull_source_issues
    @client.auto_paginate = true

    ilist =[1,2,3]
    my_array = []

    ilist.each do |i|
        puts "Adding issue [#]: #{i} \t from: #{REPO}\n"
        my_array.push(@client.issue(REPO , "#{i}", :state => 'all'))   # works
        #@issues.push(@client.issue(REPO , "#{i}", :state => 'all'))   # fails!
    end
    @issues = my_array

    puts "Found #{issues.size} issues."
end
```

But it seem that I *have* to use the intermediate `my_array`, as pushing into `@issues` array immediately, fails.

**Drawback**

This way also seem very inefficient as I seem to make a request for each item, instead of fetching them all at the same time and then select the ones needed. In addition it also selects for *pull requests*, which is not wanted. (*Because PR's are also *issues* in GH.)

I often see the iterator looking like this:

```rb
@issues = @client.issues(@source_repo, :state => 'all')

@issues.each do |source_issue|
    print "Processing issue: #{source_issue.number}  (#{n}/#{issues.size})\r"
    if !source_issue.key?(:pull_request) || source_issue.pull_request.empty?
        # Add each issue to (new?) @issues here
    end
end
```

But I can't get that to work either.

---

**How can I *push()* each issue into the `@issues` array immediately?**
(And how can I do it more efficiently?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing elements in the @issues array will fail because it´s not initialized (`@issues = []`).

After taking a look at the octokit documentation you have 2 possibilities.
Unfortunately you can´t query multiple issues by their numbers with one request.

You can either do:

```rb
@issues = [1,2,3].map{ |issue_number| client.issue(REPO, issue_number, state: 'all') }
.reject(&:pull_request)
```

or:

```rb
@issues = client.issues(REPO).select{ |issue| [1,2,3].include?(issue.number) }
.reject(&:pull_request)
```

It really depends on the number of issues in the repo and the number of issue numbers that you want to query. If you´re really just querying 3 issue numbers, i´d go with the first approach. Otherwise i´d stick to the latter.

When working with expensive operations (such as making calls to an API) it´s also useful to create a lazy enumerator:

```rb
[1,2,3].lazy.map{ |issue_number| client.issue(REPO, issue_number, state: 'all') }
```

This will prevent the array from being built immediately and if you´d only want the first n elements, the remaining issues won´t get pulled.

Also mind that when using the latter approach you´d need to go through the different [pages](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb#pagination) or disable pagination.

Comment: Hi Dario. Thank you. Look promising, but what are the performance differences of using `map` vs. `select`? Also, in my last snippet, it seem that you can pull down all in **one** request, and then just select the ones you want with the `each do`.

Comment: So what map does is, its taking the array on which you are calling it and returns a new one with the given block applied on each element. Select is used to filter an array based on the return statement of the given block. Essentially the map approach is what you tried in your first snipped and the select approach is what you tried with the `each_do`. If you have only a few issue numbers it will be more performant to use the map approach, especially if the repo has many issues. The select approach is more performant if the repo has few issues because all of them are queried at once.